# PowerShell script fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use the PowerShell script below with PSv5 to automate some manual processes but it keeps failing and I cannot figure out why. When I try to debug it in ISE, I get the following error and no output file is generated:

```
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:15 char:53
+ $HeaderLine, ${$DestinationFile} = Get-Content -Path <<<<  $SourceFile.FullName
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

```bsh
# BEGIN SCRIPT
#
# Collect all the files in the directory
$SoureFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\raw' -Filter '*.txt'

# Create the destination file
$DestinationFile = (New-Item -Path 'c:\done' `
-Name ('CombinedSources-' + (Get-Date -Format 'ddMMMyyyy') + '.txt') `
-ItemType File -Force).FullName
$DestinationFile

# Loop source, files, remove header line, append to the destination file
ForEach ($SourceFile in $SoureFiles)
{
$HeaderLine, ${$DestinationFile} = Get-Content -Path $SourceFile.FullName
${$DestinationFile}`
| Out-File -FilePath $DestinationFile -Append
}

# Sort the Destination file content and replace with sorted unique lines
(Get-Content -Path $DestinationFile `
| Sort-Object { [string]$_.split(',')[1,2] } ) `
| Get-Unique `
| Out-File -FilePath $DestinationFile -Force
#
#END SCRIPT
```

Comment: Where is it failing? What have you tried?

Comment: How is it failing? Can you post the output?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44395657/edit) to include the actual error message you get.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Also, what is your expected outcome? Running the script generates no errors, so I'm assuming by failing, you mean that it's not giving you the desired results.

Comment: If you just run the very first statement by itself in the shell, does the `$SourceFiles` variable contain *anything*?

Comment: I'm not sure how to validate if it contained anything, but it did not generate an error:  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> # BEGIN SCRIPT
#
# Collect all the files in the directory
$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\raw' -Filter '*.txt'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
# BEGIN SCRIPT
#
# Collect all the files in the directory
$SoureFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\raw' -Filter '*.txt'

# Create the destination file
$DestinationFile = (New-Item -Path 'c:\done' -Name ('CombinedSources-' + (Get-Date -Format 'ddMMMyyyy') + '.txt') -ItemType File -Force).FullName


# Loop source, files, remove header line, append to the destination file
ForEach ($SourceFile in $SoureFiles)
{
   Get-Content -Path $SourceFile.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $DestinationFile -Append
}

(Get-Content -Path $DestinationFile | Sort-Object { [string]$_.split(',')[1,2] } ) | Get-Unique | Out-File -FilePath $DestinationFile -Force
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED

The problem was my PowerShell version.  The script was written on a Windows 10 system, which was running PSv5.1.  It never even occurred to me to check the version of PS on my Windows 7 work system (PSv2).  Once I upgraded the PS version on my work system, the script worked perfectly...